# TinyMCE - Reset font-family/size on selected text

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, tinymce

I need to reset the actual `font-family` or `font-size` on a selected text

[image]

Let me explain:
On my **JCE joomla** editor, when I select a text and click on `font-size` title in font size dropdown, the `font-size` on my selection text is removed/reset/clear.

[image]

Now, I'm looking for the same result with **TinyMCE**. I tried a lot of things with CSS or jQuery, but nothing worked.

If you have any idea how I can make that or just a way?

Comment: you must do it on jquery, which version of tinymce are you using ?

Comment: Is this a Wordpress or Joomla question?

Comment: @mickmackusa it's for wordpress. But i explain what i can make with Joomla i cant with Wordpress